# Initialize a subclass from a superclass in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, subclass

I have created a **UIImage** subclass named **MyImage**.
**MyImage** obviously responds to every method originally implemented by **UIImage**. I would like to completely hide UIImage implementation, so for example MyImage redeclares a method like:

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets;
```

to

```
- (MyImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets;
```

I attempt to write the implementation like:

```
- (MyImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets {
    UIImage *original = [super resizableImageWithCapInsets:capInsets];
    MyImage *result = [[[self class] alloc] initWithUIImage:original];
    return result;
}

- (id) initWithUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    // HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD???
}
```

but I stopped at initWithUIImage method. How can I achieve such a behavior without using composition?

Comment: Maybe you can consider making your class a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). This way you can expose only methods you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that.  Its a lot of unnecessary code with a high risk of breaking something.  Don't redeclare these methods.  Is there a specific reason that you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is simple and it is called: INHARITANCE.

Do not do inaritance but provide some class which owns UIImage. It will be easier and more relialeble.

Another issue is that you didn't expain why you need change something in `UIImage`! I'm prety sure yuo are trying to resolve some simple problem in nasty way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot do what it seems like you're attempting to do. MyImage IS a UIImage, meaning it implicitly has all methods and properties of UIImage.  You can add new ones, but never remove existing ones.

And UIImage is used all over the system APIs. What exactly are you attempting to accomplish by doing this?